# Find largest number formed with numbers of an array

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, numbers, bubble-sort

The task is to find the largest number formed with the numbers of an array. For example:

input: 7, 56, 94, 1
output: 947561

In the code, I compare ab and ba, and then sort the numbers using bubble sort.

My code works for 80% test cases, but I cannot find the mistake. Where or which case haven't I taken into account? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

typedef long long int ll;

ll len(ll n){

    ll l = 0;
    while (n > 0){

        n /= 10;
        l++;
    }
return l;
}

ll concade(ll a, ll b){

    ll con = a * pow(10, len(b)) + b;
return con;
}


void swap(ll *xp, ll *yp){

    ll temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}

void bubble_sort(ll arr[], ll n){

    ll i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++){

            if (arr[j] == 0 && arr[j+1] != 0)
                swap(arr[j], arr[j+1]);

            if (concade(arr[j], arr[j+1]) < concade(arr[j+1], arr[j]))
                swap(arr[j], arr[j+1]);
        }
    }
}

int main(){

    ll n;
    while (cin >> n){

        if (n == 0) 
            break;

        ll arr[1000000];
        for(ll i = 0; i < n; i++){

            ll x;
            cin >> x;
            arr[i] = x;
        }
        bubble_sort(arr, n);
        for (ll i = 0; i < n; i++)
            cout << arr[i];
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with inputs, expected outputs and actual outputs

Comment: Note that `pow` is a floating point function and may not return accurate integer results for larger numbers

Comment: Tried any debugging of a failing case yet? What where your findings?

Comment: `typedef long long int ll` -- Stop using these crazy macros and simply use `int64_t`.  The code looks like it is littered with number `11`'s.

Comment: @AlanBirtles what can I use instead of pow?

Comment: Instead of `pow()`, use multiplication in a loop.   That achieves accurate integer results.  It may sacrifice a little speed, but that sacrifice is insignificant unless the power is ever large  (which it isn't in your code).   In any event, rather than presenting unreadable code and asking for help debugging, try checking the algorithm (i.e. the logic of what it does, not the code).

Comment: Do you know whether any of your arithmetic operations incurred overflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The greedy approach works fine with your question.

1. Sort the numbers according to the first different digit.
2. Combine them (in descending order)

here is the implementation in C# (syntaxes are similar)

Note: you can use string for large datasets, numbers works for small datasets. and also consider using a faster algorithm for sorting rather than bubble sort

```
private static long F(List<int> numbers)
    {
        // 1
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Count; j++)
            {
                if (Compare(numbers[i], numbers[j]) > 0)
                {
                    var temp = numbers[i];
                    numbers[i] = numbers[j];
                    numbers[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        // 2
        long bigNumber = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
        {
            int numberOfDigits = NumberOfDigits(numbers[i]);
            bigNumber = (bigNumber * Pow10(numberOfDigits));
            bigNumber += numbers[i];
        }

        return bigNumber;
    }

    private static long Compare(long n1, long n2)
    {
        while (n1 > 0 && n2 > 0)
        {
            var difference = FirstDigit(n1) - FirstDigit(n2);
            if (difference != 0)
            {
                return difference;
            }
            n1 %= Pow10(NumberOfDigits(n1) - 1);
            n2 %= Pow10(NumberOfDigits(n2) - 1);
        }
        return FirstDigit(n1) - FirstDigit(n2);
    }

    private static long Pow10(long times)
    {
        long s = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
        {
            s *= 10;
        }
        return s;
    }

    private static long FirstDigit(long n)
    {
        while (n >= 10)
        {
            n /= 10;
        }

        return n;
    }

    private static int NumberOfDigits(long n)
    {
        int digits = 1;
        while (n >= 10)
        {
            digits++;
            n /= 10;
        }

        return digits;
    }
```

and this is the solution using C# special syntaxes:

```
    private static string F(List<int> numbers)
    {
        return string.Join("", numbers
            .Select(x => x.ToString())
            .OrderByDescending(x => x));
    }
```

Comment: input: 17, 156, 194, 11; output?

Comment: @greybeard thanks for your input example, comparing was a little more complex than I thought. it's been fixed.

Comment: *Order by characters from left to right* has been called [lexicographic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order). You could just handle *digit strings*…

Comment: @greybeard yes, of course. I also added a short answer; using a higher level of abstraction.